# How to find which process owns the named posix semaphore lock?

Tags: c, linux, posix, semaphore

I used named semaphore to synchronize multiple processes in my system. One of the process acquired the lock and exits without releasing the lock.Now none of the process able to acquire the semaphore lock.

> named semaphore file present in /dev/shm/ directory (i.e)
>   /dev/shm/sem.XXXX.

I am trying to find the culprit process by adding debug logs in the code. Is there any other way we can use to find the process id associated with the named semaphore?

Comment: Hi Allan, I could not pin point which process holds the lock. But lsof command shows all the process which uses the semaphore. Your in put helped me a lot.

Comment: we can use "stat" command to find when the last access/modified time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the command `lsof /dev/shm/sem.XXXX` (`lsof` = list of open files) to find which process has the file. `fuser` is also an equivalent for what you are trying to achieve. You can just call those commands from your c program via `system()` call or `fork()`/`exec()`. Then you have to analyse the output of the command to take the proper actions.

For more details on portability issues, have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18614/alternatives-for-lsof-command